# Is there a reason why German Anakin did not bring freedom to his new empire?

Tags: star-wars, translation, revenge-of-the-sith

In the Revenge of the Sith, just before his fight with Obi-wan, Anakin says his famous words:

> I have brought peace, freedom, justice and security to my new empire.

In the German translation of the Revenge of the Sith, Die Rache der Sith, there is a slight change.

> Ich habe etwas vollbracht. Ich habe frieden, gerechtigkeit und sicherheit für mein neues imperium geschaffen.

I am still a german learner but this roughly translates into:

> I achieved something. I created peace, justice and security for my new empire.

It can't be because of the length, as the German translation has 31 syllables while English only has 20. Both stresses four words, so it can't be that as well.

The reason is probably freiheit rhyming with both gerechtigkeit and sicherheit sounds weird. However, if this is the case, any other two can be removed instead of freiheit.

Is there any explanation for this? The comments of producers or voice-actors are preferred but any explanation is welcome.

Comment: You say it can't be because of length, but the german is 11 syllables longer than the english already.  If they added freedom as well doesn't it make it even harder to make a convincing dub?

Comment: @iandotkelly They could have removed the first sentence which is not there in English original.

Comment: True.  I wonder why they felt the need to add that sentence as well.  Could it entirely be to synchronize the words and lip shapes better?

Comment: _"Both stresses four words"_ Yet there's only three words mentioned in the German version. So where is the fourth?

Comment: @Flater I am not really sure exactly how stress works in German language but "vollbracht" also sounds stressed.

Comment: @iandotkelly It seems very plausible. Whatever they did, since German verbs go to end in this tense, they had to rush the end. But with this extra sentence, they might have managed better lip synching in the beginning.